# Reversed iterator from top to bottom, right to left, instead of completely reversed

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector` that goes in the following order:

```
0 3 6
1 4 7
2 5 8
```

using a reverse iterator I get the following output:

```
8 5 2
7 4 1
6 3 0
```

The output I need is:

```
6 3 0
7 4 1
8 5 2
```

how would i go about getting that required ordering, at first it seems like i would be able to get a `reverse iterator position - vertical size` but that gets tricky when my vector is something like this:

```
0 6  12
1 7  13
2 8  14
3 9  15
4 10 16
5 11 17...
```

Comment: I am sure there more than one ways to accomplish that goal. Post what you have tried, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: don't use an iterator perhaps? loop and calculate which index to print manually.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: And... what is a square or rectangular vector? A vector of row vectors? A vector of column vectors? A linear vector and **you** see it as a 2D container? Currently I feel your question *unclear*...